# Need a simple open source solution to export 2D table data into PDF and Word format

Tags: java, swing, report

guys. In our project, we need to add a new feature which is to export some test result data into PDF and Word format file for user. The structure of test result data in our system is generally simple 2D table (some may be a little complex that has cell consolidation). Is there any stable and mature java open source solution for this? Or should we use any report solution like BIRT (but we feel such solution may be too heavy weight for this feature)? Because the deadline of this project is tough, to save some investigation time I post a question here and want to get some suggestions. Any suggestion will be very appreciated, thanks. By the way, our project is a Swing application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JasperReports allow export to PDF and DOC, it might be easier than using POI and iText.

Answer (score 1):

As time is short and this is a new feature, you might temporize by writing a comma-separated-value file with a name acceptable to Excel. At a later time, implement a more robust solution using [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/) or something similar that your research identifies.